# Passing dynamic property in css method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When i was doing like below, it was not working!! can you please help me why is it so?

```
var propertyName = 'left';
var propertyVal = $("body").width();

$('nav').css({ propertyName: propertyVal , 'position': 'absolute'});
```

Comment: Please add more info and your research, hypothesis, code. Show us what you've done. We are here to help you learn, not free software support.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you can't use a variable as the name of a property in an object using the syntax you have. Instead you need to use bracket notation to define that property and its value. Try this:

```
var cssSettings = { 'position': 'absolute' };
cssSettings[dynCssProperty] = widthMenu;
$('nav').css(cssSettings);
```

Alternatively, you can make two calls to the `css()` method, setting each attribute individually:

```
$('.nav').css('postion', 'absolute').css(dynCssProperty, widthMenu);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can do this way:

```
$('nav').css(propertyName, propertyVal)
        .css('position', 'absolute');
```

Also you can use the `array` notation to add:

```
cssProperties[propertyName] = propertyVal
```

Comment: Hi @Praveen your way is totally correct.. but if there are many dynamic properties which want to add under css method, then this solution will be tedious to write again and again..